# .net Does Attribute Routing affect ModelState in ApiControllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a project I am working using `ApiController`. Some of the `ApiControllers` are using a route template and some are using `RouteAttribute` I am using `ModelState.IsValid` to tell whether the requests are good or bad.

I am getting a weird behavior in the `ApiControllers` decorated with `RouteAttribute`

My method signatures look like this

```
    Get([FromUri] AwesomeModel model)

    [Route("magic")]
    Get([FromUri] AwesomeModel model)
```

They are in different controllers but are using the same model. What is happening is the `ModelState.IsValid` with a `RouteAttribute` looks as expected unless there is no query string at all in the request. In which case the `ModelState.IsValid` is true when it should be false.

The one using the route template works even if there is no query string. Am I using the `RouteAttribute` slightly wrong, or are there just issues with the ModelState when using the `RouteAttribute`?

If it is an issues with the `RouteAttribute`  messing with the `ModelState` binding does anyone have any solutions?

I am currently getting around it by using a function I made in my projects base `ApiController` called `IsBadRequest()` that returns a bool. I check the Actions parameter using the `ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()` against the Actions arguments using `ActionContext.ActionAguments` and if there are any required parameters without corresponding arguments I update the model state and return false. I was hoping there is a better solution because I have to use reflection to update the `ModelState` correctly.

Comment: I would start by creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am no longer at my computer but will create one as soon as I am home. I would like to add my colleague was able to reproduce the problem in his project simply by adding a Route Attribute to an action.

Comment: I've had similar problems using `Route` and binding complex types from query string values. In my case, a type with default values for its properties gets instantiated correctly with no query string using convention routing, but is null when `Route` is added. Haven't got to the bottom of it yet, but there's definitely something fishy happening when `Route` and `FromUri` are combined.